# Dynamic Swift Framework: Fatal error: unable to find bundle

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcframework, dynamic-frameworks

I have a framework that imports several Swift Packages.

One such package uses Bundle.myModule for resources. Here is the code use for **.myModule**

```
extension Foundation.Bundle {
static var myModule: Bundle = {
    let bundleNameIOS = "xxxx"
    let candidates = [
        // Bundle should be present here when the package is linked into an App.
        Bundle.main.resourceURL,
        // Bundle should be present here when the package is linked into a framework.
        Bundle(for: CurrentBundleFinder.self).resourceURL,
        // Bundle should be present here for package UI Tests.
        Bundle(for: CurrentBundleFinder.self).resourceURL?.deletingLastPathComponent(),
        // For command-line tools. */
        Bundle.main.bundleURL,
        // Bundle should be present here when running previews from a different package (this is the path to "…/Debug-iphonesimulator/").
        Bundle(for: CurrentBundleFinder.self).resourceURL?.deletingLastPathComponent().deletingLastPathComponent().deletingLastPathComponent(),
        Bundle(for: CurrentBundleFinder.self).resourceURL?.deletingLastPathComponent().deletingLastPathComponent(),
    ]

    for candidate in candidates {
        let bundlePathiOS = candidate?.appendingPathComponent(bundleNameIOS + ".bundle")
        if let bundle = bundlePathiOS.flatMap(Bundle.init(url:)) {
            return bundle
        }

        if let bundle = Bundle(path: "\(Bundle.main.bundlePath)/\(bundleNameIOS).bundle") {
            return bundle
        }
    }
    fatalError("unable to find bundle")
}()
```

}

Then we I build the framework and embed it inside another project I get the error

**Fatal error: unable to find bundle**

But the Package that this is failing in is inside the XCFramework

the folder path "App/Frameworks/myFramework" does not contain any bundles

I have tried all of the follow:

- [Swift Package: Fatal error: unable to find bundle named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66213111/swift-package-fatal-error-unable-to-find-bundle-named)
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650158
- [Swift Package Manager - Type 'Bundle' has no member “module” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64407950/swift-package-manager-type-bundle-has-no-member-module-error)
- https://forums.swift.org/t/unable-to-find-bundle-in-package-target-tests-when-package-depends-on-another-package-containing-resources-accessed-via-bundle-module/43974/6

Please any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you